# Tweaking the table after shapefile import?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm importing shapefiles to Postgresql with the shp2pgsql command line tool.

```
shp2pgsql -s 3035 -W "latin1" foo.shp | psql
```

Should I do some table (SQL) tweaks after that? Or is the import fine after that?

Answer (score 1):

`shp2pgsql` translates a shapefile and its attribute table to sql commands. It does all the heavy lifting for you so the **result should be workable** as it's being produced, and it's a starting point for you to **optimize** if you want by:

1) Create spatial index (- I flag in shp2pgsql). You can create a spatial index in an already created table by
`create index idx_foo_geom on [schema].foo using gist (geom)`

2) make sure connection roles can create/delete/view the table. If you use superuser credentials ignore this.

3) depending on the use you can create indexes in the functions (eg
`create index idx_foo_area_geom on [schema].foo using btree (st_area(geom))`

4) You can add some rules/triggers to enforce data consistency

and of course any optimization or fiddling with the database comes with the intended use of your data.

Comment: when should I create an index? I have a table with lot of read process and an other table with load of read, update, insert, delete processes. Should I "index" both of them?

Comment: update, delete and select statements should benefit from the presence of a spatial indexes if their `where` clause contains  spatial filters (eg where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)). It's up to you as a database administrator to decide if you need them or not.

Comment: dunno if original has an id, if not please create a gid (gid serial) : ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN gid serial;